# htaccess rewrite rule magento 2.4.5 prepends pub/

Tags: magento2.4, htaccess, magento2.4.5

I have got 2 rewrite rules which work, but pub/ is added to the url when i dont want that.
I add the rules to pub/.htaccess. If i add them to the .htaccess in the magento root, nothing happens.

The URL `https://www.example.com/xerox-everyday-toner-for-tn242y-yellow-toner-cartridge-006r04226` becomes `https://www.example.com/pub/xerox-everyday-toner-for-tn242y-yellow-toner-cartridge`.
My rules are to remove the SKU at the end, but as i have URLs like `https://www.example.com/refilled-hp-953xl-ink-cartridge-multipack` I need the first rule as well.

My rules are:

```
RewriteRule -cartridge-multipack$ - [L]
RewriteRule (.+-cartridge)-.+$ $1 [R=302,L]
```

This is to rewrite some old product URLs that have been indexed by google. (The 302 is just while im testing, this will eventually become 301 when  know it works)

Where do i add rules to stop pub/ being added?

Comment: How many URL are needed to rewrite? https://meetanshi.com/blog/magento-2-url-rewrite/ has a good guide. Do you need different things?

Comment: Its quite a few URLs. The guide you have wont work for me. I forgot to mention in this post that i use a stock, price, product import plugin which does not seem to save old URLs on product update/import (reported issue to devs). I already have a custom route module that i made to create a search when product isnt found but i want to replace this because every time a bot crawls an incorrect URL it creates a search which obscures legitimate search data and makes my search_query table pretty big.